# What is Continuous Deformation?

Tags: general-topology

Today I had attended my introductory course of topology, and the lecturer used the term "continuous deformation" without proposing its formulated definition.

Had looked up wikipedia, it generally shows the concept of homeomorphism, not with exact terminology "continuous deformation"

I roughly guess the concept/definition of topology is with which to make a opens sets upon a given set so that we can generalize our understanding of continuity.

To define continuity of function, one generally needs to define the right-next element in domain set, so the concept of topology helps it to be realized I guess.

Is there any further reading, recommendation or intuitive explanation to understand the term "continuous deformation" clearly?

Comment: Basically, for most contexts a continuous deformation is a bijective continuous function. So if I have some set and I apply a continuous bijective function to it then the resulting set is a continuous deformation of the first set.

Comment: @TonyS.F. How to define continuous function not just in real number? wikipedia provides continuity biased to real number

Comment: Continuity can be defined for any mapping between topological spaces. A map $f:X\to Y$ is continuous if, for any open set in $Y$, the pre-image $f^{-1}$ of that open set is an open set in $X$. In other words, for a map to be continuous we require that all open sets in $Y$ are the image of an open set in $X$.

Comment: @TonyS.F. Today I learned to define topology, and we agreed to call any elements of $\tau$ - open set. Thus my question is, to define the concept of continuity in your comment, do we always have to define topology first? I mean do I have to check whether the function's domain and codomains are following the definition of topology or not before talking about continuity of the function?

Comment: To define continuity you should define what a topology is first, yes, because without the concept of open sets you cannot say that the preimage must be open. But, I think you want to know something slightly different. The most common case is that we have two topological spaces, $(X,\tau)$ and $(Y,\sigma)$ and we want to see if a map between them, $f:X\to Y$, is continuous. This requires that the sets $X$ and $Y$ already have a topology. However, sometimes we have a map $f:X\to Y$ already and we define the topology on $X$ or $Y$ in such a way that $f$ will satisfy the definition fo continuity.

Comment: @TonyS.F. What a clear assertions. Thank you so much. Well understood.

Comment: A usage I have seen quite a few times in research papers: A deformation of a space $X$ is a continuous function $f:X \rightarrow X$ which is homotopic to the identity map. But that is quite a different context from an intro course. Possibly the lecturer was being (intentionally) vague when they said that.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that the lecturer was referring to homotopy. A homotopy between two continuous functions $f,g: X \to Y$ is a continuous function 
$$H : X \times [0,1] \to Y$$ such that $H(x,0)=f(x)$ and $H(x,1)=g(x)$. It was probably referred to as a continuous deformation because it was looking at the image of $f$ and $g$. For example, if $f$ and $g$ are paths in your space, then $H$ will describe a continuous deformation of the image of the first path to the image of the second one.